# T-shape text underline in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a text underline effect with this look:
[image: desired effect]

So far I have managed to create this effect:
[image: what I have so far]

using this code:

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 222px;
}

ul li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

ul li a:hover:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 25px;
  transform: translateX(100%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <ul>
```

Now I need to add that missing part (arrow down triangle maybe) at the intersection of the two perpendiculars but I don´t know how to do that.

[image: missing part]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have `:before` left to use, create triangle with it.

```
ul li>a:hover:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    left: calc(50% - 15px);
}
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 222px;
}

ul li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

ul li a:hover:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 25px;
  transform: translateX(100%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

ul li>a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the a:before selector, and draw a triangle.
How to draw a triangle with CSS is explained [over here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).

After you have drawn the triangle you can place it over your borders.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors to achieve this. Check the below snippet

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
}

ul li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

ul li a:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 4px;
  background: black;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

ul li a:hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 10px;
  bottom: -22px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```